# Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module only in Release configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Few days ago we had problem with our release build for IOS. We were getting

> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

error. In Debug configuration everything went well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time we found out that when you run your code in develop configuration your index.js is created and provisioned to device via localhost connection. But when you're in release, you use

> react-native-xcode.sh

script as a build step in xcode. This script creates index.js for you. BIG problem is that if this script can't find your entry point to the application, it doesn't fail, it builds index.js successfully without any modules. In that case, just add entry point to your application to build step. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

my command line looked like:
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh ../index.js

Answer (score 0):

In you appDelegate find jsCodeLocation and then replace with below code.

```
   var jsCodeLocation : URL? = nil

  #if DEBUG
      jsCodeLocation = URL.init(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true")
    #else
      jsCodeLocation = CodePush.bundleURL()
    #endif
```

Basically app is not able to locate the bundler .
In my case when bundler run it shows index.js instead of index.ios.js so modified the path accordingly that works for me