# Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm starting with React Native development and I encountered an issue in the very beginning. When trying to run my app I get errors:

> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
>   Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
>   Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import DefaultRouter from './src/navigation/DefaultRouter'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <DefaultRouter />
      </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
  };
```

index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

DefaultRouter.js:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from '../screen/LoginScreen';
import DefaultTabBar from '../navigation/TabBar';

const DefaultRouter = createSwitchNavigator({
    LOGIN_SCREEN: {
        screen: LoginScreen
    },
    TAB_NAVIGATION: {
        screen: DefaultTabBar
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'LOGIN_SCREEN',
    headerMode: 'none'
})

export default createAppContainer(DefaultRouter)
```

Other files are simple `Component` subclasses.

The issue manifests regardless if I run the app from Visual Studio Code or from terminal with `react-native run-ios`

I looked through existing answers and I didn't find anything that could point me in the right direction:
[React-Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969858/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)
[React Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397800/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module-calling-ru)
[module appregistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128692/module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication)
[Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module and Cant find variable: Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381142/module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module-and-cant-find-variable-c)
[React Native Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133086/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)
[Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module only in Release configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283521/module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module-only-in-release-configura)

I'm stuck and I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run either `npm cache verify` or `cd ios && pod install` and then `npm run ios`

Comment: why?  Add reasoning here, explanation please.

Comment: sometimes some library wasn't cleaned up very well, then to fix that developer can just reinstall or clean it manually

Comment: this answer helped me for this error, I updated a NPM package and had to link it again!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after a git commit cause the error, then I found the wrong code in the commit is:

```
static emitter = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModule) : DeviceEventEmitter;
```

where the NativeModule is null because I have not implemented it on iOS !

When I edit it to

```
static emitter = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? {} : DeviceEventEmitter;
```

then the error `Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)` is gone!

Answer (score -1):

No worries... Simply close all the server processes and node and run again your application using

```
react-native run-ios/android
```