# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TrackPlayer.RATING_HEART') && Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-track-player

For the past 1.5 days or so, I tried to get react-native-track-player working and I just can't make it happen. No matter what I try I always end up running into the same error block:

```
ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TrackPlayer.RATING_HEART')
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I set it up both with `react-native expo` and 'normal' `react-native` (according to react-native [docu](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)) both with `JS` and `TS`. And for all variants of that I tried:

- Deleting/reinstalling node-modules
- `npm cache verify` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752968/module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)),`react-native start --reset-cache` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication)) and some other cache reset/deletion things.
- I've copied the [example](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player/tree/main/example) from their GitHub repo.
- I updated and/or reinstalled pretty much every library (incl. `node`)

All of those efforts ended in the exact same error.

So ye, I literally don't know what to do anymore. I'm a beginner at both react-native and app dev in general. So to be honest, it's very likely the mistake I'm making is super stupid/simple. But I just can't find it. I would be more than grateful for any advise.

EDIT - Dependency error: [image]

EDIT 2: Solution - `react-native` removed `jcenter` between `v0.64` `v0.65` which was root of all my problems, check my answer below for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: `jcenter()` will be removed for sure. Check [this](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/1235) GitHub thread for more infos on how to procede with `react-native-track-player`.

Ok, while cloning the example from their [repo](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player/tree/main/example) worked (thanks @AngwarGul) I still wanted to figure out why that was. So it turns out, that the fundamental reason for the error was in the `build.gradle` file.

I've been using `react-native@0.65.1` and wasn't aware that from `v0.64` to `v0.65` `jcenter` [was removed](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.2&to=0.65.1) from react-native. So, when running `react-native run-android` the app couldn't be built since it couldn't find jcenter. So ye, I probably could have realized that earlier, but I was looking anywhere but there.

TL;DR: Adding `jcenter()` to the build.gradle file solved the whole issue for me (see pic below). So, in case anyone else does the same stupid mistake, here's your solution ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately by Looking the [Documentation of react-native-track-player](http://react-native-track-player.js.org/getting-started/) , This package doesn't support expo [Expo and Expokit support](http://react-native-track-player.js.org/install/#expo-and-expokit-support)
[image: http://react-native-track-player.js.org/install/#expo-and-expokit-support]

## How I manage to run the Example Project from Package

### Steps:

- Cloned react-native-track-player
- Separate out the example project from package
  [image: Separated Example Project]
- Remove `postinstall` from package.json's scripts
  [image: remove post install script]
- add package in dependencies `"react-native-track-player": "^2.0.1",`
- `yarn install` or `npm install`
- `yarn android` or `npm run android`

#### Result

[image: Example Project running]

Comment: actually there are ways now, see [here](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/audio-playback-in-background). But regardless, I'm currently using plain react-native, so it really _should_ work. Did you manage to get `rntp` working?

Comment: @MichaBrugger can also mention the steps that you used to run to example project and what error message said?

Comment: I used `npx react-native start` (also tried `npx react-native run-android` but there I just get stuck in an endless 'waiting for server'). The error message prints exactly what I pasted above. Sometimes the second message repeats 2-5 times in slight variations. Also it complained about some dependecy issues, so I had to tinker with the react version a bit.

Comment: @MichaBrugger I have updated the answer please do check example project is running

Comment: https://github.com/anwargul0x/TrackPlacerExample.git you check the code here

Comment: I tried exactly this, but then I run into a dependency error. I pasted into the OG post.

Comment: @MichaBrugger clone the repo  and simply run yarn install and yarn android , if it still gives any error let me know here or in the repo

Comment: I'm blown away - it works! Thanks a lot! Now I need to understand why. When using npm install I literally get the same error I always got, but using yarn install it works perfectly. I always thought yarn and npm achieve the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237028/discussion-between-anwar-gul-and-micha-brugger).